# Spring batch writing to multiple tables based on order object

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am consuming order xml and converting them to order object using spring batch. The structure of order object is something like below:

```
public class Order{

prop1
prop2
---
propn
List<Item> items;
List<Shipping> shipping;
List<Billing> billing;
----
}
```

Now `prop1 - popn` will go to order table but items, shipping and billing information will go to different tables and for simplicity lets assume they one to many relationship. Currently, I am parsing the xml and populating the order bean and pushing some date using `JdbcBatchItemWriter` to order table only. In the documentation I see `compositeWriter` but don't see any good example.I am sure some one already implemented this kind of solution before so want to get some idea on this. It would be great if i get some information on how to achieve this with a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

The `ComposedItemWriter` passes each item in the list passed to the `ItemWriter` and passes it to each of the list of delegate `ItemWriter` implementations.  So you'd configure it as follows (each of the `writer*()` methods refers to a writer to a table you need to write to):

```
@Bean
public CompositeItemWriter<Order> orderCompositeItemWriter() {
    List<ItemWriter<Order>> delegates = new ArrayList<Order>();
    delegates.add(writer1());
    delegates.add(writer2());
    delegates.add(writer3());

    return new CompositeItemWriterBuilder<Order>()
            .delegates(delegates)
            .build();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try and let you know :)

Comment: Hi Pinaki - I was checking this example as I'm having a similar case here, where I need to read a csv file and parsing each row to a different DOA based on the first three lets of the row, and then I need to write each row to a table in the DB, i wonder if you were successful of doing so from the above reply by Michael, here is my issue post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57557032/reading-csv-file-with-spring-batch-and-map-to-domain-objects-based-on-the-the-fi?noredirect=1#comment101618449_57557032] ..thank you@Pinaki Mukherjee